# The angular diameter distance for a radiation dominated universe

Tags: cosmology, radiation, distance

I'm attempting to work out the angular diameter distance for a radiation dominated universe, with $k=0$ and $\Lambda=0$.

I have gotten myself to this point:

$$
D_{A}=\frac{1}{H_{0}(1+z)}\int^{z}_{0}\frac{dz}{\sqrt{\Omega_{M}(1+z)^{3}+\Omega_{\gamma}(1+z)^{4}+\Omega_{\Lambda}+\Omega_{k}(1+z)^{2}}}
$$
Is this the correct statement for the angular diameter distance? (Confusing on my part due to the many defintions my lecturer has used, e.g., distance, angular diameter and angular diameter distance).

Now, just to clarify, for a radiation dominated Universe with $k=0$ and $\Lambda=0$, would this become:

$$
D_{A}=\frac{1}{H_{0}(1+z)}\int^{z}_{0}\frac{dz}{\sqrt{\Omega_{\gamma}(1+z)^{4}}}
$$

Is it then just best practise to work through the integral? Pulling $\Omega_{\gamma}$ outisde, and pushing $1/(1+z)$ inside the integral?

I'm not sure if I should push the $1/(1+z)$ as I have used $D_{A}=D_{M}/(1+z)$ where $D_{M}$ is:
$$
D_{M}=D_{H}\int^{z}_{0}\frac{dz}{E(z)}
$$
Where $E(z)=\sqrt{\Omega_{M}(1+z)^{3}+\Omega_{\gamma}(1+z)^{4}+\Omega_{\Lambda}+\Omega_{k}(1+z)^{2}}$. So, if I evaluate $D_{M}$ first can I then just divide by $(1+z)$ to get $D_{A}$?

Comment: What textbook/papers have you used?

Comment: [This](http://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/9905116v4.pdf)?

Comment: Yes. That is very close. It was a site on NED Caltech, I'm assuming that how close they are is because the arXiv notes were derived from latter.

Comment: You need simply to solve the integral and to neglect other contributions from matter, dark energy, etc, since the universe is in radiation dominated era.

Comment: So, what I have stated is correct?

Comment: No, you can't push outside of the integral since the integral depend on redshift. Just solve the integral which is a simple formula.

Comment: No I meant push the factor of (1+z) inside the integral. (I was taking Omega for radiation out since it is redshift independent)

Comment: You can't push$(1+z)^{-1}$ inside the integral because the integral is over redshift. Just solve the integral as it is there and then multiply by the $(1+z)^{-1}$.